# Bit Summation in Solidity

Tags: solidity, gas

Is there an efficient way to perform bit summation in Solidity? Let's say I have 256 bools, and I want to count how many of them are true. Looping over all 256 would be extremely gas-expensive.

I can optimize by encoding all 256 into a single uint256, where each bool represents one bit. They use a lot less storage now, but counting up how many are true still seems to require looping through each bit of the uint256. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Brian Kernighan algorithm to count the number of set bits in a uint256

```
function countSetBits(uint256 x) public pure returns (uint8) {
    uint8 count;
    while (x != 0) {
        x &= x - 1;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, doing bitwise operations and saving bools as bits in a number is more efficient while looping than looping through an array.

Also, remember that calling a `view` or `pure` function is free. So if you call a smart contract to count the number of on 'bits' in an array or uint, it's free. Unless it modifies the state, then it spends gas.

Take a look at the following code. I create both implementations, saving the bits in a `256` bit number, setting specific indices, getting values from specific indices, and counting them using a `for` loop. It would be more efficient if Solidity implemented `log2` math function since we would only need to loop about `log2(boolsUint)` times since this would let us know about what bits are on (lower bits, higher bits). But in my implementation, I loop through 255 bits just in case.

Notice how the implementation of the `bool[255]` array consumes more gas when looping through it and modifying the state. I created 2 versions of each functions, one that consumes gas and one that does not.

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

// Author: Jeremy Then

contract CountBits {

    uint256 public boolsUint;

    bool[255] public bools;

    uint8 public bitCounts;
    uint8 public boolsCount;

    function toggleBoolUintAtIndex(uint8 index) public {
        uint256 bIndex = 1 << index;
        boolsUint = boolsUint ^ bIndex;
    }

    function getBitAtIndex(uint8 index) public view returns(uint8) {
        uint256 bIndex = 1 << index;
        uint8 result = uint8((boolsUint & bIndex) >> index);
        return result;
    }

    // It's a view function, it will not cost gas unless you modify the state.
    function getCountOfOnBits() public view returns(uint256) {
        uint256 boolsUintCopy = boolsUint;
        uint8 _count = 0;
        for(uint8 i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            if(boolsUintCopy & 1 == 1) {
                _count++;
            }
            boolsUintCopy >>= 1;
        }
        return _count;
    }

    // This is the same as getCountOfOnBits, but modifies the state, thus costs gas
    // Spends about 102813 gas
    function getCountOfOnBits_gasSpender() public {
        uint256 boolsUintCopy = boolsUint;
        uint8 _count = 0;
        for(uint8 i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            if(boolsUintCopy & 1 == 1) {
                _count++;
            }
            boolsUintCopy >>= 1;
        }
        bitCounts = _count;
    }

    // Bools array impl

    function toggleBoolAtIndex(uint8 index) public {
        bools[index] = !bools[index];
    }

    function getBoolAtIndex(uint8 index) public view returns(bool) {
        return bools[index];
    }

     // It's a view function, it will not cost gas unless you modify the state.
    function getCountOfTrueBools() public view returns(uint256) {
        bool[255] memory boolsCopy = bools;
        uint8 _count = 0;
        for(uint8 i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            if(boolsCopy[i]) {
                _count++;
            }
        }
        
        return _count;
    }

    // This is the same as getCountOfTrueBools, but modifies the state, thus costs gas
    // Spends about 345157 gas
    function getCountOfTrueBools_gasSpender() public {
        bool[255] memory boolsCopy = bools;
        uint8 _count = 0;
        for(uint8 i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            if(boolsCopy[i]) {
                _count++;
            }
        }
        boolsCount = _count;
    }

    function getBools() public view returns(bool[255] memory) {
        return bools;
    }

}
```